# How to fix jumping page and covering of page by sticky menu in Elementor?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive, sticky, elementor

I am using a sticky menu in Elementor. On desktop it's ok. On mobile, the sticky header/menu covers the first element, but when I scroll, it the element/page jumps down and leaves white space. When I fix spacing to make it visible initially, there is even more white space. How do I stop the jumping so I can just adjust the spacing?

Check it out on mobile: duecucina.com/about-us/

Comment: Hi Sophia, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you set your header sticky/fixed then your structure underneath the header will jump up. It will jump up about the same height your header is.

So to fix this you just need to add a margin-top for your content (wrapper element underneath your header) but only when your header is set sticky/fixed. So when the header has the class fixed or headerScroll.